# Is it necessary to check for error after calling a Mongoose function?

Tags: mongoose, error-handling, try-catch

Example:

```
let { id } = await User.findOne({ email }, '_id').exec();
if (!id) throw "error";
```

Testing these two instructions, I realize that when `findOne` function doesn't find the document (id) for that email, it generates an error, and jumps directly to catch. (I'm using try-catch).

In that case, the second instruction, the if, never runs. And so that if instruction seems useless: it will be executed only when no error in User.findOne

So: is it necessary to check for error after calling a Mongoose function?
Or ALL Mongoose function generate a error by themselves, and you only need to use try-catch?

Answer (score 1):

When the `Model.findOne` function doesn't find a match it doesn't throw an error and won't jump to the `catch` block in a `try/catch`. It returns `null`. In your code, if you want to ensure that the query found a document (i.e not `null`) then you would need to do what you have done with a `if (!id)` statement.

However, in your case you are trying to detructure an object that does not have a property (it's not even an object, its `null`) and that has nothing to do with Mongoose. That's just JavaScript and would throw:

```
Cannot destructure property 'id' of '(intermediate value)' as it is null.
```

To illustrate the mongoose return values, your document might look like this:

```js
{
   _id: "6504794e507561a33ce92789",
   email: 'bob@gmail.com',
   age: 50
}
```

Then your query in a `try/catch` :

```js
try{
   const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'sally@yahoo.com' })
   // No document found
   // user == null
   // No error was thrown
   // Code continues to execute
} catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```

Whereas in the case of an error it might look like this:

```js
try{
   const user = await User.findOne(50)
   // Error thrown
} catch(err){
   console.log(err);
  // err == 'Parameter "filter" to findOne() must be an object, got "50" (type number)
}
```

Please be aware that the return value is different for `Model.find` when no document is found. In those cases, the return value is `[]`, so an empty array.

In either case it is good practice to check for `null` (for `findOne`) and check for `[]` (for `find`) so that you can interrupt control flow and return a message to the user that nothing was found.

To summarise this would be good practice for `Model.findOne`:

```js
try{
   const user = await User.findOne({ email: 'sally@yahoo.com' })
   if (!user){
    // Handle empty result 
   }
} catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```

This would be good practice for `Model.find`:

```js
try{
   const user = await User.find({ email: 'sally@yahoo.com' })
   if (!user.length){
    // Handle empty array result 
   }
} catch(err){
   console.log(err);
}
```